# Why does my php code loop infinitely?

Tags: php, debugging, web

I have a function `GetLetters` that returns

1. `a` when I give it `1`
2. `b` when I give it `2`
3. `z` when I give it `26`
4. `aa` when I give it `27`
5. `ab` when I give it `28`

Basically you'd get the idea, this is my solution however it is looping indefinitely when I supply any input value above 26, does anyone know what's wrong with it ?

```
function GetLetter($amt){
    if($amt<=26){
        return strtolower(chr(64+$amt));
    }
    $letters=array();
    while(true){
        $quotient=$amt%26;
        array_unshift($letters,GetLetter($quotient===0?26:$quotient));
        $amt=floor(($amt-1)/26);
        if($amt===0){
            break;
        }
    }
    return implode("",$letters);
}
```

Comment: You could just say `while($amt != 0) { ... }` instead as well. This'd solve the int-to-float comparison problem as well.

Comment: @Marc I like the `while(true)` pattern, but others may disagree of course

Comment: `while (true)` and then later on break on a specific condition isn't clear when you later read the code. `while (true) ... break` should only be used in special occasions, which this one clearly isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), you're comparing floats. Try `intval()`.

So change

```
if($amt===0){
```

to

```
if(intval($amt)==0){
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `floor` returns float, and you use `===`, not `==` for comparing with integer(0), so float(0) === int(0) always false.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an alternative way to do it (note though that it is O(n)):

```
function getLetters($n) {
    for ($chr = 'a'; --$n;) ++$chr;
    return $chr;
}
```

(If you increment a character in PHP it'll first go from `a..z`, then `aa..zz` and so on, just as you want.)

Comment: Much better solution. Generally you want to avoid recursion when possible.. especially recursion with a while(true) loop :P

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use a repetition statement like the `while` statement you shouldn't utilize `float` type to determine the end of the repetition. Floating-point numbers are never perfectly precise, so they aren't the ideal for condition statements.